# ActiveRecord true/false query for all objects in a collection having an attribute equal to a value

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a collection of `Bit`s. They have a 'fiddled' attribute.

How can I query to see if all my `Bit`s in a collection have `fiddled` equal to true?

Currently I do

`bits.select { |bit| bit.fiddled }.count == bits.count`

This looks inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for is there any `bits` with `fiddled` as `false`

```
unless bits.where(fiddled: false).any?
  //logic
end
```

Comment: I like that. I was trying to reduce his original query in my head and forgot about `.any?`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is more efficient as I don't have the program to test it, but you could do this and see which one tests out faster:

```
 Bit.where('fiddled = ?', false) == 0
```

Thus if any are false it will return `false` and if all are true it will return `true`. This of course is predicated on you having some sort of restrictions in place so that `fiddled` is never null. If it is a boolean column that is set to `Not Null` then it should be pretty reliable.

Just as an aside, having a boolean column gives you and automatic `?` method. So

```
 b = Bit.first
 b.fiddled?
```

will return either true or false based on the column value.

If you truly want efficiency, don't have Rails do this, have a database view do it for you. That is the fastest way, as the DB is optimized to do this far better than Rails.

You can create a model called FiddledBits that represents a view in your DB:

Log into your DB and create the view:

```
CREATE VIEW fiddled_bits AS
SELECT fiddled
FROM bits
WHERE fiddled = false;
```

Then add your dummy model:

```
class FiddledBit < ActiveRecord::Base
  #this is a class that represents a view in the DB.
  def self.all_true?
    FiddledBit.count == 0
  end
end
```

Now you can call:

```
FiddledBit.all_true?

#=> true
```

Comment: Of course if it is all as simple as your example you might only see a millisecond of difference. But as you scale up, DB views are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
bits.where(fiddled: false).exists? # => true or false
```

This will execute something like `SELECT 1 FROM bits WHERE fiddled = false` which will be faster than your current solution as well as faster than the suggestion to use `any?` as that solution would do a count of the records which could potentially be more expensive.